# How to repeat this statement in R probably using apply()

Tags: r, loops

It might seem a silly question but how to repeat this line for 152 times and I would not like to use a for loop,since later it will not be efficient with larger data sets:

```
reviews = as.vector(t(mydata)[,1])
```

**mydata** is a row in a data.frame and
**reviews** is an array of characters, also 
*[,1]* is just the first row

The output could be a matrix or worst case a data.frame.

I tried something like this, but it did not work :

```
testing = apply(mydata, 1, function(x) {as.vector(t(mydata[,x]))})
Error in t(mydata)[, x] : subscript out of bounds
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Quick data sample:

```
> reviews = as.vector(t(mydata)[,1])
> class(reviews)
[1] "character"
> length(reviews)
[1] 14
> reviews
[1] "I was involuntarily"                                                                   
[2] "I was in transit"                                                                                   
[3] "My initial flight"                                                                             
[4] "That still left"                                                                                           
[5] "After disembarking"                                                                    
[6] "customs and proceed to my gate."                                                                                                                                                                        
[7] "I arrived"                                                                                                                                     
[8] "When my boarding pass was scanned"                         
[9] "No reason was given for the bump."                                                                                                                                                                      
[10] "The UA gate staff"
[11] "I boarded Air Canada."                                                                                                                    
[12] "After arriving"                                                                                  
[13] "I spent 5 hours"                                                                                                           
[14] NA
```

**mydata** data.frame:

```
> class(mydata)
 [1] "data.frame"
 > length(mydata[,1])
 [1] 152
 > mydata[,1]
 [1] I was involuntarily... .
 [2] First time... . 
 ...
 ...                                                                                     
 152 Levels: First time . ...
```

I have about 30.000 of these, but I want to start small, so only 152 of paragraphs split in individual sentence and put into a data.frame. Each row in the data.frame has 5-15 sentences.

I want to to be able to access each row as an array since I need to perform some action on each row of the data.frame

Packages used: plyr, sentiment(downloaded from [here](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sentiment/) and installed manually)

**EDIT 2:**

```
 dput(myData[1:6, 1:6])
 structure(list(V1 = structure(c(70L, 41L, 94L, 114L, 47L, 49L), 
 .Label = c(" Air Canada", 
 "their service", 
 "hours for de-icing", 
 "have flown BA", 
 "my booking", 
 "If the video screen", 
 "Frankfurt flights", 
 "and another 150 lines of text data",
```

Comment: You should supply a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and desired output data to make it clear what you are trying to do and to test any possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick I did my best to explain the situation, I hope that this could be at least a mediocre reproducible example

Comment: @UtherPendragon, you are asking advice on how to use `apply` on a data.frame yet you have not provided a representative example. Since you claim it is rather large, ***make up some data*** that looks somewhat like you want (perhaps 2-3 words each sentence) without clobbering our screens with comments for an airline. The link @MrFlick provided has sections that specifically discuss **"producing a minimal dataset"** in the likely event the section **"copy your data"** is impractical in this question.

Comment: @r2evans I am sorry I could not provide what you asked for. I edited the question a lot. Please take a look again.

Comment: I am getting down-voted because of bad formatting / structuring or because it is a bad question ? Is it understandable that I only want to repeat one line but not using a for loop, more likely an apply() statement ?

Comment: by bad structuring/ formatting I meant not giving a proper reproducible example

Comment: I will add `dput(mydata[1:6, 1:6])` in a minute

Comment: I added output for `dput(mydata[1:6, 1:6])`

Comment: Thank you for finally adding data ... unfortunately, it's incomplete. Since you don't (yet) have the ["Informed"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) badge, your recommended reading (that started with @MrFlick's [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)) now includes the StackOverflow [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). There are several other good sections immediately after the tour, such as [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recommended way to ask a question, focusing on the fact that your actual data is too big, too complicated, or too private to share.

**Question**: how to `apply` a function on each row of a data.frame?

### My data:

```
# make up some data
s <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
mydata <- as.data.frame(matrix(strsplit(s, '\\s')[[1]][1:18], nrow=3, ncol=6), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
mydata
##      V1          V2         V3      V4         V5     V6
## 1 Lorem         sit adipiscing      do incididunt     et
## 2 ipsum       amet,      elit, eiusmod         ut dolore
## 3 dolor consectetur        sed  tempor     labore  magna
```

If you have data that you can use directly, then as has been suggested multiple times in the comments, the use of `dput` is helpful:

```
mydata <- structure(list(V1 = c("Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"),V2 = c("sit", "amet,", "consectetur"), V3 = c("adipiscing", "elit,", "sed"), 
    V4 = c("do", "eiusmod", "tempor"), V5 = c("incididunt", "ut", "labore"), V6 = c("et", "dolore", "magna")), .Names = c("V1", 
    "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

In either order, state (i) what you are trying to do, and (ii) what you have tried and how it is not working.

### My desired output:

Converting a row into a vector is ... confusing. A row is already a vector, so I don't know what you are ultimately trying to do. So, I'll come up with something short an to the point: I want the words on each row to be in reverse alphabetical order, perhaps like this:

```
##       V1    V2         V3      V4     V5          V6
## 1    sit Lorem incididunt      et     do  adipiscing
## 2     ut ipsum      elit, eiusmod dolore       amet,
## 3 tempor   sed      magna  labore  dolor consectetur
```

This is a good time to show the code you've tried, errors you've encountered, and/or *how* the unerring output is not what you intended.

## Answer, generically:

Several ways to do something to each row:

1. Use `apply`, though this breaks if you have `numeric` and `character` intermingled. If you try this, you'll see that the output is actually the *transpose* of what you may think, in which case you'll need to wrap (and all of the other `*apply`-based suggestions here) with `t(...)`. It's a little confusing, but it's necessary here. Oh, and they'll all be a `matrix` class which can easily be converted to `data.frame` if needed.

   ```
   ret <- apply(mydata, 1, function(r) {
       do_something(r)
   })
   ```
2. Use `sapply` or `lapply` on row indices. Note that these are returning lists or vectors of results, so you'll need to convert into whatever format you ultimately need.

   ```
   ret <- sapply(1:nrow(mydata), function(i) {
       do_something(mydata[i,])
   })

   # if you need to keep each row's results rather encapsulated, use one of the following:
   ret <- sapply(1:nrow(mydata), function(i) {
       do_something(mydata[i,])
   }, simplify=FALSE)

   ret <- lapply(1:nrow(mydata), function(i) {
       do_something(mydata[i,])
   })
   ```
3. Use `foreach` and `iterators`.

   ```
   library(foreach)
   library(iterators)
   ret <- foreach(df=iter(mydata, by='row'), .combine=rbind) %do% {
       do_something(df) # just one row of mydata this time
   }
   ```

In the case of my (contrived) question, here are several ways to do it:

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(mydata, 1, function(r) sort(r, decreasing=TRUE))))
##       V1    V2         V3      V4     V5          V6
## 1    sit Lorem incididunt      et     do  adipiscing
## 2     ut ipsum      elit, eiusmod dolore       amet,
## 3 tempor   sed      magna  labore  dolor consectetur

as.data.frame(t(sapply(1:nrow(mydata), function(i) sort(mydata[i,], decreasing=TRUE))))
## same output

library(foreach)
library(iterators)
## notice the use of as.character(...), perhaps still a blasphemy
## to the structure of a data.frame
ret <- foreach(df=iter(mydata, by='row'), .combine=rbind) %do% {
    sort(as.character(df), decreasing=TRUE)
}
ret
##          [,1]     [,2]    [,3]         [,4]      [,5]     [,6]         
## result.1 "sit"    "Lorem" "incididunt" "et"      "do"     "adipiscing" 
## result.2 "ut"     "ipsum" "elit,"      "eiusmod" "dolore" "amet,"      
## result.3 "tempor" "sed"   "magna"      "labore"  "dolor"  "consectetur"
```

Comment: `ret <- sapply(1:nrow(mydata), function(i) {
    do_something(mydata[i,])
})` ... this is what I need it. Thank you very much, I appreciate it